# how to declare variable in TSQL and use in multiple statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I declare a variable in T-SQL and use it in multiple statements?

For example:

```
DECLARE @STRDT DATE
SET @STRDT '2017-01-01'

SELECT TOP(10) * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE START_DATE = @STRDT;

SELECT TOP(10) * 
FROM TABLE2
WHERE START_DATE = @STRDT;
```

Right now, I am able to run the first statement correctly, but unable to use the declared variable in my second statement. I get an e error

> Must declare @STRDT

when I am running the second select statement in SQL Server.

Comment: Right now i am able to run the 1st statement correctly but not able to use the DECLARE varible in my second statement. it giving me error "Muct declare @STRDT" when i am running the 2nd select statement in MS SQL server.

Comment: `SET @STRDT = '2017-01-01'`

Comment: Does it work if you remove the semicolon after the first SELECT statement? Semicolons are kind of like "GO", in that they kind of finalize the previous code and anything following is a totally different code block.

Comment: This code works fine - if you execute the **whole** code as one block. However, if you highlight the second `SELECT` and execute *only* that `SELECT` - then **of course**, the `@STRDT` is never declared. Variables in T-SQL are **not** persisted - you must declare them before each use

Comment: Its working when i am running the all query but when i am running one  statement  and again the other it's not working

Comment: "but when i am running one statement and again the other it's not working".  Of course it won't work if you only highlight the second statement, because you miss the declaration statement.

Answer (score 2):

Variables exist only within a certain scope which is within a statement that is being run. Therefore, when you have logic like this in a stored procedure it'll be run within the same scope because it's the same batch so the variable will "work" for both statements. It's the same thing when you want to run it manually - you have to run both statements together in order to get what you want. That's simply how it works and if you run both statements at the same time - the variable "works" in both - or multiple - statements.

To read up more on them, consult the following sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql
- https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/declare_vars.php

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, its not working for second statement because of the presence of the semi-colon ;

If you want to use the variable in both statements, remove the semi-colon between the two statements and run the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

The OP does not indicate which client app they're using to execute the SQL statements. Probably SSMS, since that's the usual MS SQL Server tool? Or maybe Azure Data Studio?

In my case, I've been trying to execute such multi-statement batches in  DBeaver for MS SQL Server T-SQL. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77540198), you can (*sometimes*) make this work by surrounding the statements with `BEGIN` and `END`.  For example, for the simple query below, you can execute the following using `Ctrl+Enter` or `Ctrl+\` anywhere in the `BEGIN`-`END` block. It will open two tabs since there are two `SELECT` statements.

```sql
BEGIN
DECLARE @StartDate datetime='1/1/2023 12:00:00 AM',
    @EndDate datetime='12/31/2023 12:00:00 AM';
SELECT @StartDate as [Start Date];
SELECT @EndDate as [End Date];
END
```

For more complex queries, it can be necessary to position the cursor on the `BEGIN` statement and then use `Ctrl+Enter` or `Ctrl+\`. (Or, alternatively, highlight the entire `BEGIN`-`END` block and press `Alt+X`.) In particular, I've found this to be necessary when the SQL statement(s) contain `with cte1 (...)...` Common Table Expressions.

I've also been running into more complex batches of SQL statements that execute successfully in SSMS, but that DBeaver rejects because it complains that there is a syntax error. I have not found a solution to that problem.

Bottom line with respect to DBeaver: it seems it simply won't execute some MS Sql Server T-Sql multi-statement batches that SSMS and Azure Data Studio execute correctly.