# DBeaver, How to declare variables and use them?

Tags: sql, variables, dbeaver

i just want to know if it is possible to declare variables on the DBeaver´s sql editor and use them on a query

Answer (score 101):

You have to enable variable processing in the "SQL Processing" settings of DBeaver -> Window -> Preferences -> Database -> Editors -> SQL Editor -> SQL Processing. There is a block on `Parameters` with settings you can change. See the [Dynamic Parameter binding](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/SQL-Execution#dynamic-parameter-bindings) section on the wiki.

[image]

You should then be able to do:

```
@set date = '2019-10-09'

SELECT ${date}::DATE, ${date}::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE
```

which produces:

```
| date       | timestamp           |
|------------|---------------------|
| 2019-10-09 | 2019-10-09 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: Note that `@set` is a DBeaver command. If you append `;` it'll become part of the variable value!

Comment: In version 23.3.0.xxx the path is: DBeaver -> Window -> Preferences -> Editors -> SQL Editor -> SQL Processing -> Parameters -> Enable SQL parameters.

Answer (score 24):

Yes you can, using `:`.

An example:

```
SELECT * FROM "SYSIBM".SYSDUMMY1
WHERE IBMREQD = :YOUR_VARIABLE
```

Comment: my idea is to declare that variable on the top of de code for example above the "Select" declare a value to that variable like ..... my_variable = "success" ..

Comment: I think this is the only way

Comment: FYI, OOTB I was able to run using: `:foo` `$foo` and `${foo}`

Comment: You can use `@set` to define variables with either syntax. DBeaver will populate any placeholder that's defined in preferences.

Comment: But how do you define the variable? Dbeaver is finicky and throws a syntax error when using something like this

my_var = "hello"

select :my_var

Comment: You have to write `@set` all **lowercase**! Using `@SET` did not work for me using DBeaver version 22.3.0.202212041619.

Answer (score 9):

In the DBeaver SQL editor you can type the following:

```
-- define variable
@set my_var='hello SQL world'

-- call variable
select :my_var
```

You can also use `${my_var}` to reference the variable; `$my_var` however did not work for me. I am using DBeaver v. 21.1.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the incredibly helpful post from @nicoschl, here are a couple of minor improvements:

```
-- using declarations
@set datex_start = cast('2120-01-01' as date) as date_start;
-- datex_start is the var name
-- casting the value in the declaration saves us the work later
-- the var can be given a default fieldname (e.g. "date_start")

-- run as a standalone command since the subsequent SELECT statement doesn't return values when it's all run together

select 
    ${datex_start}
;
```

This will return a value "2120-01-01" with a fieldname of "date_start".

Comment: set with ';' at the end defines variable with that ';' at the end in dbeaver , so if you need clean value do set without ending ';'

Comment: On Oracle I ended up using `@set i_date = (date '2000-01-01')` (which makes it relatively simple to copypaste storedproc queries and just prepend the input parameters with `:` like `select :i_date as col1 from dual`

Answer (score 2):

Use BEGIN and END. It works for me. Example:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @name VARCHAR(10);
  SET @name = 'My Name';
  SELECT @name AS NAME;
END;
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what is needed to use regular MS SQL Server T-SQL variable declarations. I have not found this documented elsewhere!

Comment: I've written this up with some additional details @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/77566399

Answer (score -1):

You have to enable at Dbeaver settings:
Top Window > Preferences > and then see print below (updated 2022/08).

[image: Updated screenshot]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).