Oracle - How to build a dynamic query for use in DBeaver
I come from a SQL Server background. How should I write the below to be able to run in DBeaver against an oracle database? I got bits of it from other questions here but cannot make it work in full.
variable stringpattern varchar2(1000);

EXEC :stringpattern := '%t_carvalue%'

SELECT * 
FROM all_source 
WHERE UPPER(text) LIKE UPPER(concat('%',:stringpattern,'%'))
;
select *
from all_views
where UPPER(text) like UPPER(concat('%',:stringpattern,'%'))

Thank you.

As with SQLDeveloper, you have 2 buttons in DBeaver, execute statement or run as script, here you have to run the code as a script. Also in DBeaver you should check the parameters in the Preferences->Editors->SQL Editor->SQL request, there is a config about if empty lines should terminate statement having a stupid "Always" default value.

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56566119/1509264

VARIABLE (VAR) and EXECUTE (EXEC) are SQL*Plus commands that are run by the client application before any SQL statements are sent to the database. They are not valid syntax recognized by Oracle databases - just by client applications that support SQL*Plus commands.
In DBeaver, you can use the set command to set a variable:
@set stringpattern = 't_carvalue'

SELECT * 
FROM all_source 
WHERE UPPER(text) LIKE '%' || UPPER(:stringpattern) || '%';

select *
from all_views
where UPPER(text) like '%' || UPPER(:stringpattern) || '%';

Note: Using @set may behave like a substitution variable rather than a bind variable.
Note 2: In Oracle, CONCAT takes exactly 2 arguments, not a variable number of arguments. You can use the || operator to concatenate strings or CONCAT(CONCAT('%', UPPER(:stringpattern)), '%').
Looking at the DBeaver documentation for SQL Execution:

To execute the script natively, press Alt+N or click Execute -> Execute SQL Script natively on the context menu or SQL Editor -> Execute SQL Script natively on the main menu or in the main toolbar. Upon activation, a setup wizard is launched, which allows you to configure the parameters for script execution before the script is launched in the native client like PLSQL, MySQL, or SQLPlus. The results are displayed in a text field in the format of console output. It is handy when functions are not supported by DBeaver drivers and require more specialized clients or when the function is weighty, and a faster client is needed.

This should run the script using SQL*Plus, in which case, you could also use the SQL*Plus EXECUTE and VARIABLE commands since they would be processed in SQL*Plus and not by DBeaver.

This worked! Thanks for prompt response.

This is how I worked it out.
I had to create a copy of all_views due to ORA-932 issues with field 'text' being of type LONG.
CREATE TABLE AALL_VIEWS_MINE as
SELECT Owner, View_Name, to_lob(TEXT) Text
from all_views;

Then the script becomes this
@set stringpattern = 't_carvalue'

SELECT 'SP'SourceType , a.OWNER, a.Name, A.TEXT
FROM all_source  a
WHERE UPPER(text) LIKE '%' || UPPER(:stringpattern) || '%'
;
-- system table all_views has known issues with field text ORA-932 error.
SELECT 'V'SourceType , a.OWNER, a.View_Name, A.TEXT
from AALL_VIEWS_MINE a
where UPPER(text) like '%' || UPPER(:stringpattern) || '%'
;

