# Two select statements, two where clauses, one number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I am trying to create a query with two diferent `SELECT` statements and two diferent `WHERE` clauses. But the `WHERE` clauses are the same number. They cannot be joined because one is in `varchar` and the other is `int`. But I want to input the number only once.

Maybe this will make it easier to understand. I have this:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(Apples)
        FROM
            applestracker
        WHERE
            ( seller LIKE '3')
    )
    +
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(Oranges)
        FROM
            orangestracker
        WHERE
            ( sellernumber = 3 )
    ) AS Total
```

I want it so that I don't have to put the number 3 twice.

Something like this :

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(Apples)
        FROM
            applestracker
        WHERE
            ( seller LIKE 'Number_of_seller' )
    )
    +
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(Oranges)
        FROM
            orangestracker
        WHERE
            ( sellernumber = Number_of_seller )

    -- Number_of_seller is 3
    ) AS Total
```

Is something like this possible. I don't want to have to repeat the number of seller twice even though they are two types. Is it possible to create a where clause standby and then put the number in the end?
Thank you

Join is not possible in this case. I have try to create a table but I am not being able to create a single table with the sum of two different data bases

Comment: Use a variable with the value `'3'`?

Comment: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to declare variable in TSQL and use in multiple statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49766698/how-to-declare-variable-in-tsql-and-use-in-multiple-statements)

Comment: You could use a common table expression (CTE) to provide an initial `select` with the magic value: `with OnlyOnce as ( select 3 as NumberOfSeller ) select ( select ... ) + ( select ... ) as Total;`. Aside: Why `seller like '3'` rather than `seller = '3'`? Do you need to invoke pattern matching on a pattern with no wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variable up front and use it in different parts of your query, convert it to different types as needed.

```
DECLARE @var INT;
SET @var = 3;

Select 
(
  select count(Apples)
  from applestracker
  where 
  seller like CAST(@var AS VARCHAR(11))
) 
+
(
  select Count (Oranges)
  from orangestracker
  where
  sellernumber = @var
)  
AS Total
```

Comment: Your `DECLARE` and `SET` statements can be combined into a single `DECLARE @var int = 3;` line. Secondaly, the `LIKE` operator should be changed to `=` because `'3'` is not a valid `LIKE` pattern. The explicit `CAST` use is redundant as SQL Server will perform the conversion implicitly.

Comment: _"You don't think I already know that"_ - Honestly, I didn't think so, actually - because there's no good reason to use the old-style declare statements, and using `LIKE` with a non-pattern value is also _bad SQL_.

Comment: @Dai Don't you think I know all that :) I prefer not to combine declare and set statements, I think it's more clear and understandable when written separately. For the rest of the query I didn't change what OP's example was. I am sure it's not a real query just sample. And I have left explicit CAST just to point out the possibility of using it. 
After all, there is your answer nearby that address all the mentioned issues.

Comment: @Dai But, nevertheless, still OK to point it out, for future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At risk of being verbose, you can `DECLARE` that as a variable: use `DECLARE @number_of_seller int = 3`,

SQL Server will implicitly attempt to convert `varchar` values to `int` in your `WHERE` clauses, though your query [won't be SARGable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162263/what-does-the-word-sargable-really-mean). Or if you use a separate `@variable` for the `varchar` version it should use indexes on that column - though you won't need to specify `3` more than once:

Like so:

```sql
DECLARE @number_of_seller       int         = 3;
DECLARE @number_of_seller_chars varchar(10) = CONVERT( varchar(10), @number_of_seller );

SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT( a.Apples )
        FROM
            applestracker AS a
        WHERE
            a.seller = @number_of_seller_chars
    )
    +
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT( o.Oranges )
        FROM
            orangestracker AS o
        WHERE
            o.sellernumber = @number_of_seller
    ) AS Total
```

...that said, SQL Server is smart enough to recognize constant-expressions in queries, so the above query can be rewritten as below without any performance impact:

```sql
DECLARE @number_of_seller int = 3;

SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT( a.Apples )
        FROM
            applestracker AS a
        WHERE
            a.seller = CONVERT( varchar(10), @number_of_seller )
    )
    +
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT( o.Oranges )
        FROM
            orangestracker AS o
        WHERE
            o.sellernumber = @number_of_seller
    ) AS Total
```

Comment: A `varchar` variable with a value of `'3'` would likely be safer. Presumbly the reason the OP uses the clause `seller LIKE '3'` is because `seller` is a `varchar` (and may have non-`int` values). Passing a `varchar` value maintains SARGability in *both* clauses (as the variable would be implicitly cast to an `int` instead when needed) and avoids conversion errors on the column `seller`. *If* the variable could contain a non-valid `int` value, then you could `TRY_CONVERT` it to an `int` in the query against `orangestracker`.

Comment: @ThomA Good points - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much both. The SQL tool I am using does not have declare. So I will ask internally what I can use instead and try. I will tell you if it works. Thank you so much

Comment: *"The SQL tool I am using does not have declare."* What do you mean by that? `DECLARE` is a T-SQL operator; it doesn't matter what tool (SSMS, ADS, DBeaver, VSCode, etc, etc) you're using to run the query. Are you, perhaps, *not* using SQL Server?

Comment: @alexandraCoito What tooling are you using, exactly? Even if you can't use a statement-batch (for `DECLARE`) you could move this all into a `FUNCTION`.